# Python - can't connect to database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm learning python , I'm trying to connect to database:

1. OS Ubuntu 13.04
2. I have running the apache and localhost
3. Im using eclipse pydev
4. I have installed the mysql connector downloaded from here:http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ (a .deb file)
5. I have installed the sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
6. List item

This is my code (simple)(with proper indent):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                         passwd="root", # your password
                         db="Ayuda") # name of the data base
except Exception as a:
    print a

cur = db.cursor() 
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")

for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row[0]
```

So I get this error:

> (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

How do I solve this?

Comment: What is the result of `service mysql status` when run from the command line?

Comment: when i run in the eclipse , appears this in the console:(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elfstone/Documents/workspace/FirstPythonProject/DB.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")
NameError: name 'cur' is not defined                                      are you refering to this?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved: I used another code taken from mysql example of use: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/myconnpy_example_connecting.html

this is my code now:

```
import mysql.connector

from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                         user="root",
                         passwd="root",
                         db="Ayuda")

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")

    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exists")

    else:
        print(err)
else:

    cur = cnx.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mitabla")

    for row in cur.fetchall() :
        print row[1]

    cnx.close()
```

I still don't know why I could'connect the other way.